# The dual of $C_0^k(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $C_0^k(X)$ be the space of a $k$ times continuously differentiable complex, valued smooth functions, which vansih outside of $X$.

The norm on $C_0^k(X)$ is given by
$$ ||f|| = \sum_{| \alpha | \leq k} || \partial^\alpha f ||_\infty $$

How does the Banach space dual space of $C_0^k(X)$ look?

Comment: The purely algebraic dual?

Comment: ;) No, the topological one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it is isomorphic to the direct sum of the dual of $C_0(X)$ and a $k$-dimensional vector space (the precise answer is in "Linear Operators", Dunford/Schwartz).

Comment: I will check the reference. Something similar was also my guess. Thanks